# Print Variable Array of Specific Worksheets to a Single Printout

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to print specific worksheets from my Excel workbook to a single printout.  There are additional sheets in my workbook that should not print.

The name of the first worksheet to be printed will be constant ("Recipe").  The names of the other worksheets to be printed will vary (they will all have the prefix "Pie" and different suffixes).  The number of sheets to be printed will vary from project to project.

For example,
In project #1 the workbook will include the following worksheets:  "Recipe", "Pie - Apple", "Pie - Pumpkin", "Ingredients", and "Tools".

In project #2 the workbook will include the following worksheets:  "Recipe", "Pie - Custard", "Pie - Apple", "Pie - Key Lime", "Pie - Blueberry", "Ingredients", and "Tools".

I would like to print the "Recipe" worksheet and every worksheet that starts with "Pie" to a single printout.  The following code allows me to unitize the desired worksheets while weeding out the rest:

```
Sub PrintArrayOfWorksheets()
Dim PrintCollection
PrintCollection = Array("Recipe", "Pie - Apple", "Pie - Pumpkin")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(PrintCollection).PrintOut
End Sub
```

This code works; however, it requires me to manually enter the elements of the array for each project.  Please recommend a method of automatically updating the array to include the worksheets that meet the criteria above.  Or, please recommend some other method entirely.

I've tried a couple different unsuccessful ideas, and I can share those if requested.

Kind regards,
Tony

Comment: If you have any questions, please post your comment here. You may not edit my answer to ask a question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added a piece of code in yours that dynamically populates your array with the name of the sheets that fits the requirements.

```
Sub PrintArrayOfWorksheets()
    Dim PrintCollection() As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    ReDim PrintCollection(0 To 0)
    i = 0

    'Dynamically populates array
    For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If LCase(WS.Name) = "recipe" Or LCase(Left(WS.Name, 3)) = "pie" Then
            ReDim Preserve PrintCollection(0 To i)
            PrintCollection(UBound(PrintCollection)) = WS.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(PrintCollection).PrintOut
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyAr
    Dim sName As String

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "Recipe" Or UCase(Left(ws.Name, 3)) = "PIE" Then
            If sName = "" Then
                sName = ws.Name
            Else
                sName = sName & "\" & ws.Name
            End If
        End If

        If sName <> "" Then
            MyAr = Split(sName, "\")                
        End If
    Next ws

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(MyAr).PrintOut
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are going to do it by string concatenation instead of by collection or allocating arrays directly you should probably not use comma as your delimiter. Commas are valid in sheet names, which could break your code. Use a character that is not valid in a sheet name, such as / \ * ? [ ] or :

Comment: Haha, except the pipe character `|` is also valid in sheet names :D

Comment: Damn! I had typed "\". Shift didn't work I guess. Amended it.

Comment: Works great, thanks.  Although, it produces one printout for each worksheet.  The line "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(MyAr).PrintOut" needs to be moved outside of the ForEach...Next loop to produce a single printout.  Thanks for your help.