# Worksheets(Array(SheetsToPrint)).PrintOut

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to create an **UserForm** for printing from a dinamically generated **ListBox** of available Sheets on my workbook. It looks like this:

[image: UserForm with Print Button]

I set **1 - fmMultiSelectMulti** in the ListBox properties to allow multiselection.
Usually, I need the sheets printed in color, as well as a copy printed in black and white. And to be sure everything looks good before spending some ink, there is a checkbox for the print preview.

So far, I managed to capture the selection and store it in a variable called **SheetsToPrint**. But the print command below is failing with **Subscript out of range (Error 9)**.

```
Worksheets(Array(SheetsToPrint)).PrintOut preview:=True
```

If I don't use the variable and change it to the following string, it works as expected:

```
Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).PrintOut preview:=True
```

And I get what I need in a single print job. **Except** for the basketball image not being shown/printed properly.

Related question: [Print Variable Array of Specific Worksheets to a Single Printout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962686/print-variable-array-of-specific-worksheets-to-a-single-printout)

My VBA Code looks like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim N As Integer
Do
N = N + 1
If Sheets(N).Visible = True Then
    SelectedSheets.AddItem Sheets(N).Name
End If
Loop Until N = Worksheets.Count
End Sub

Private Sub SelectAll_Click()
Dim N As Single
If SelectAll.Value = True Then
    For N = 0 To SelectedSheets.ListCount - 1
    SelectedSheets.Selected(N) = True
    Next N
Else
    For N = 0 To SelectedSheets.ListCount - 1
    SelectedSheets.Selected(N) = False
    Next N
End If
End Sub

Private Sub PrinterButton_Click()
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
End Sub

Private Sub PrintButton_Click()

Dim vPrev As Boolean
If PrintPreview.Value = True Then
    vPrev = True
Else
    vPrev = False
End If

With SelectedSheets
    For N = 0 To .ListCount - 1
    If .Selected(N) = True Then
        If SheetsToPrint = vbNullString Then
            SheetsToPrint = """" & .List(N) & """"
        Else
            SheetsToPrint = SheetsToPrint & ", " & """" & .List(N) & """"
        End If
    End If
    Next N
    MsgBox "Print Array:" & vbCrLf & SheetsToPrint
    Me.Hide
End With

' Color Config
If Original.Value = True Then
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    For Each sht In Worksheets(Array(SheetsToPrint))
    With sht.PageSetup
        .BlackAndWhite = False
    End With
    Next

    ' Print Original in single print job
    With Worksheets(Array(SheetsToPrint))
        .PrintOut preview:=vPrev
    End With
End If

' Grayscale Config
If Copy.Value = True Then
    Dim shtBW As Worksheet
    For Each shtBW In Worksheets(Array(SheetsToPrint))
    With shtBW.PageSetup
        .BlackAndWhite = True
    End With
    Next

    ' Print Grayscale in single print job
    With Worksheets(Array(SheetsToPrint))
        .PrintOut preview:=vPrev
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

I´ve tried many combinations and search a lot, but no luck.
Any advise is very welcome.
This is my excel file: [userform_printout_array.xlsm](https://www6.zippyshare.com/v/H02nqoxN/file.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't declared it, `SheetsToPrint` is implicitly a `Variant` already, and already an `Array`. Just write:

`Worksheets(SheetsToPrint).PrintOut preview:=True`

No need to double up. Notice how in the related question you posted they do the same thing at the end :)

Comment: I tried that already and it gives me the same error. It wasn’t my intention to double up, sorry. But my question is about the array giving problems and not how to print a single job.

Comment: @paradadf So is the issue that you're having trouble *creating* the array? Can you do `Debug.Print SheetsToPrint` before your `PrintOut` line to see what you're creating?

Comment: I don´t think creating the array is the problem. Debug.Print gives me what I expect, e.g.: "Sheet1", "Sheet2". My problem is that I can´t find what I´m doing wrong, even after looking everywhere for clues. I attached my workbook so it is easy for anyone competent in vba to tried it out. I suspect that it has something to do with dimensions of SheetsToPrint, but anything I tested didn't work :(